# How do I determine the hardware requirements for importing an OSM extract?

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu, osm2pgsql

I have a 950MB OSM extract I'm trying to import into Postgres using osm2pgsql. All attempts thus far have failed as I've been running out of hard drive space. I have no problem processing metro or individual state extracts. I've encountered nothing but problems trying to import the US Midwest region extract.

I'm likely to build a new VM to process this file so I'd like to get this right. How do I determine the hardware requirements for this process?

Comment: Ideally you'd be running this on real hardware if you want good performance - more memory and fast IO seem to be the keys to good OSM tool / database performance.

Comment: Have you tuned your Posgres database? This post summarizes the relevant parameters for tuning Postgres for spatial: http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/dataadmin/pgDBAdmin/tuning.html

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/41325/how-do-i-estimate-hardware-requirements-to-load-an-osm-extract-into-postgres